# How to get npm always fetch the last prerelease version?

Tags: npm

I am trying to use pre-release versions with npm. But it doesn't get the last prerelease version when I do `npm install`.

In my client app, I have this :

```
$ cat package.json| grep mylib
"mylib": ">1.2.4-dev.0",
```

Which at first fetched the version `1.2.4-dev.201810160008.0`

Then, I set a new pre-release version.

```
npm version --no-git-tag-version prerelease --preid=dev-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M) 
v1.2.4-dev.201810160906.0
```

I publish to a nexus repository :

```
npm publish --registry http://X.X.X.X:8080/repository/npm-private-snapshot/
```

Then I can see this new version :

```
npm view mylib versions --json
[
  "1.0.0",
  "1.2.2",
  "1.2.3",
  "1.2.4-0",
  "1.2.4-201810101547.0",
  "1.2.4-201810111027.0",
  "1.2.4-201810111231.0",
  "1.2.4-201810111445.0",
  "1.2.4-201810151548.0",
  "1.2.4-201810151550.0",
  "1.2.4-dev.201810160006.0",
  "1.2.4-dev.201810160008.0",
  "1.2.4-dev.201810160011.0",
  "1.2.4-dev.201810160906.0",
  "1.2.5-201810111819.0"
]
```

Finally, I would like to have this new version used by my client app, so I run `npm install` but it does not update mylib, the version is still the old one :

```
cat package-lock.json| grep mylib
    "mylib": {
      "resolved": "http://X.X.X.X:8080/repository/npm-group/mylib/-/mylib-1.2.4-dev.201810160008.0.tgz"
```

I have to run `rm -rf node_modules/mylib ./package-lock.json` to get it working as I expect.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/mylib ./package-lock.json
$ npm install
$ package-lock.json| grep mylib
    "mylib": {
      "resolved": "http://X.X.X.X:8080/repository/npm-group/mylib/-/mylib-1.2.4-dev.201810160906.0.tgz",
```

How can I get npm fetch the last pre-release version each time I run `npm install` ?

Comment: Maybe use a tag for that.